# c++ auto does not name a type

Tags: c++, c++11, auto

I m using keyword auto in my code

```
137       auto i = boost::find(adresses, adress);
```

On compiling with following command I get these errors

```
[vickey@tb tests]$ clear;g++ testCoverDownloader.cpp ../CoverDownloader.cpp -I /usr/include/QtGui/ -I /usr/include/QtCore/ -lQtGui -lQtCore -std=c++0x

../CoverDownloader.cpp:137:10: error: ‘i’ does not name a type
../CoverDownloader.cpp:139:8: error: ‘i’ was not declared in this scope
```

using -std=c++0x should have done the trick . What is wrong ?

Comment: the error is most likely in your usage of boost::find. with that said, please post GCC version.

Comment: Some gcc versions take `-std=c++11`. Does that fix it?

Comment: gcc version 4.6.3 20120306 (Red Hat 4.6.3-2) (GCC) , platform Fedora 16

Comment: @anthony-arnold: nope it reports unrecognized command line option

Comment: @VihaanVerma: I don't see you including the `boost` headers anywhere on the command line. How does the path get resolved?

Comment: @dirkgently I have the boost includes in /usr/include/boost .  I assume it gets picked automatically

Comment: Do you have the appropriate `boost` headers *included* in your source? Post some more source.

Comment: @dirkgently : aah crap , I included the path explicitly It ran without error :) \. My assumption that it was getting picked automatically was wrong. However In other programs where I did not explicitly specified boost path( /usr/include/boost) the programs ran fine.

Comment: @VihaanVerma: I would be tempted to think that the other programs (which ran fine) probably had the *whole* path in the `include` directive.

Comment: I agree with @dirkgently. Whenever I see this error, it's because the statement to the right of the `=` contains an error. This is a red-herring error if I ever saw one.

Comment: 18 #include <boost/algorithm/string/predicate.hpp> //boost::starts_with
 19 #include <boost/algorithm/string/trim.hpp>
These are the boost includes in the source

Comment: What types are address and addresses? Are they const?

Comment: adresses is a list of string and adress is a string

Comment: @dirkgently : here have a look at this page http://pastebin.com/BYwxwRA1 . The includes were automatic , now I m confused why did it not work with auto ?

Comment: @VihaanVerma: What about the source in question? How were the included specified?

Comment: @dirkgently: After reading your comment I included the path as `[vickey@tb tests]$ reset;g++ testCoverDownloader.cpp ../CoverDownloader.cpp -I /usr/include/QtGui/ -I /usr/include/QtCore/ -lQtGui -lQtCore -std=c++0x  -I /usr/include/boost/` The auto error was gone after this.

Comment: @VihaanVerma: Looking at the `reset` command it appears that the other sources were compiled because the `$PATH` was somehow modified to include the `boost` headers. (BTW: I've added the `-I` header include thingy as an answer.)

Comment: @dirkgently: I was using reset as to distinguish between two sequel run of the same command as it will post the error without any history of previous output. I even tried it without reset to check if that was the problem , but nope . Your answer does solve the problem but has confused me :P about the auto includes . As I thought header files in /usr/include are included automatically. The reason QT includes are needed explicitly was header files are inside  the directory QtCore/QtGUi . If in the main program includes are written as `#include<QtCore/header>` It would work find w/o gcc includes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `boost` headers aren't getting picked up for the same reason the `Qt` headers wouldn't unless you specify `-I /usr/include/QtCore/`. There is nothing special about the `boost` headers for the compiler to be partial towards them. The [Search Path](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Search-Path.html) section of GCC's documentation may help you.